# YouTube Videos disappearing after download on my Win PC

Tags: windows, download, youtube

Windows 10 ( Ver 21H2). Vivaldi Browser (Ver 5.2)Also happens in Chrome (Ver.100).
I am a premium member of YouTube and can download videos for offline viewing. So on my Win PC I downloaded many videos for viewing later.
The next day I login to YT (using my browser) and navigate to the downloads page, to my surprise all the videos have disappeared. No explanation at all. Just a blank page with the message no videos here.

As an aside, on my mobile the videos remain available for any length of time.
It's just on my PC using a browser that I have this problem.
Any ideas  will be helpful. ( Have already done the reinstall drill and tried different browsers vivaldi/chrome/firefox. all same result.).

Have raised this issue with YT Support staff and provided all details to them but no response for many days.

Best -Kevin

Comment: If you just download one video, where does it go?  On chrome if you right click on the file at the bottom of the browser and go to the file location,  are all your other videos there?

Comment: @kevdez Isn't offline viewing only a service for mobile devices?

Comment: @User552853- But the desktop browser version also has a download button next to a video. And a Download area where you can see all files downloaded - and they do download, but disappear after a while.

Comment: @cup Its not like that. It downloads to a secure area on the disk in the background. Its not like a regular file download where you can see where the file is saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, you'll only be able to download videos that you've uploaded yourself. For any other videos, the offline viewing function will only work on the YouTube mobile app.

[Source](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7381437?hl=en#zippy=%2Cwhere-is-video-downloading-available%2Chow-do-i-download-videos-from-youtube-to-my-computer%2Cwhy-arent-my-downloaded-youtube-videos-in-my-gallery)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If not available wonder why there is an option to download ??!! Also surprising that the YouTube support guy did not know this.

Answer (score 0):

Alex Taylor's answer is objectively wrong. Even in the source he provided, it can be clearly seen that you should be able to download and view videos offline using a computer, on a browser.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/11977233#zippy=%2Cdownload-videos-to-watch-offline

"If YouTube Premium is available in your location, you can download and watch videos on your mobile device. You can also download videos from your computer using Chrome, Edge & Opera browsers. We hope to bring this feature to other browsers in the future.
To download videos onto your computer:

- Visit youtube.com from your signed in YouTube Premium account.
- Go to the Watch page of the video you’d like to download.
- Below the video, click Download "".
- Once the video is downloaded, the download icon will turn black below the video "".
  If your device loses internet connectivity while downloading videos, your progress will resume automatically once you reconnect to the internet."

As of March 2023, I am still having the same issue the OP is having. Youtube downloads occasionally disappear from my downloads as well, ranging from a few to dozens, or even the entire downloads folder unfortunately.